# C++ bidirectional iterator prefix increment

Tags: c++, iterator, bidirectional

Observation 1: A C++ output iterator requires that `&r == &++r`, while an input iterator does not mention this requirement. See [C++11: 24.2.{3,4}]

Observation 2: Forward, bidirectional, and random-access iterators satisfy the input iterator requirements [24.2.{5,6,7}:1], but not necessarily the output iterator requirements unless they are *mutable* [24.2.1:4].

Observation 3: Bidirectional iterators add a prefix decrement operation, with the requirement `&r == &--r` [24.2.6].

So, is it true that a *constant* bidirectional iterator must satisfy `&r == &--r` but not necessarily `&r == &++r`, while a *mutable* bidirectional iterator must satisfy both?

Can you address how this requirement might influence an implementation?

---

MvG, below, asks the question I really meant:

- When does it make sense for a constant Forward iterator to not satisfy `&r == &++r`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an indirect way of formulating the requirements, without explicitly specify a particular implementation. In particular `&r == &++r` is a way of saying  that `++r` cannot return a proxy object. The result must be the same iterator.

Here `mutable` isn't exactly the opposite of `const` in the usual way, but means writable and again refers to the requirements for an output iterator.

A bidirectional iterator must of course support both `++p` and `--p` (by definition), but doesn't have to be writable/mutable.

The categories aren't exactly orthogonal between read/write and forward/backward movable, so the individual requirements are not a independent as they could have been. This causes some confusion.

I'm not sure if your conclusion follows from the observations, but don't think it would be an important freedom for an implementation. The fact that you have to support things like  `*++p` and `*p++` sets most of the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you address how this requirement might influence an implementation?

The obvious answer is that an `operator++()` or `operator--()` method must `return *this`, whereas a separate function `Foo& operator++(Foo& arg)` must return its argument. As this is the sane thing to do in any case, most implementations won't have to worry.

The more complicated question would be “when does it make sense for a (e.g. forward input) iterator to *not* follow the above approach”. I couldn't come up with a reasonable example yet. Even for a constant input iterator, the *type* of `++r` must be a reference to the iterator type. So any form of “proxy object”, as @Bo Persson mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11909189/1468366), would only work if that proxy object were a subclass of the iterator class. Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

I have the feeling that the requiement `&r == &++r` was simply forgotten for the output iterator case. I doubt that the authors of the spec had any specific use case in mind where this requirement would not be met. But I'm guessing, so I'll look forward to a more reliable answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the more complicated (and more interesting) question. This is really what I was getting at, so I added it above.